# Grep lines before after if value of a string is greater than zero

Tags: text-processing

Hello I have a text file containing the following info:

```
#[Tue Oct 25 00:00:02 2016] --- START OUTPUT
#CMD: XXX
END-->0<--
#[Tue Oct 25 00:00:57 2016] --- END
#RETURN: 1
#ELAPSED TIME (in seconds): 55

#[Tue Oct 25 00:05:01 2016] --- START OUTPUT
#CMD: XXX
END-->0<--
#[Tue Oct 25 00:05:33 2016] --- END
#RETURN: 0
#ELAPSED TIME (in seconds): 32
```

I want to get the `--End` line the `Return` line and the `Elapsed` line if its corresponding Return is `>` 0.

So far I have just been able to grep the Return line `grep "#RETURN:" -A 1 -B 1 f.log`

But how to i grep only if the Return is `>` 0  ?

Desired output:

```
#[Tue Oct 25 00:00:57 2016] --- END
#RETURN: 1
#ELAPSED TIME (in seconds): 55
```

Comment: Whats your desired output from this?

Comment: @heemayl Please check update

Comment: So your input file has sections separated by empty lines?

Comment: @SatoKatsura not necessarily. Some are and some are not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '/END$/ {prev=$0; next}; /^#RETURN/ && $2>0 {cur=$0; pr=1; next};\
                      pr {printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n", prev, cur, $0; pr=0}' file.txt
```

- `/END$/ {prev=$0; next}`: If the line ends with `END`, save it as variable `prev`, and go to the next line; This is the line before `RETURN`
- `/^#RETURN/ && $2>0 {cur=$0; pr=1; next}`: If the line starts with `#RETURN` and the second field is greater than 0, then save the line as `cur`, set variable `pr` as 1 (true), and go to the next line
- `pr {printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n", prev, cur, $0; pr=0}`: If `pr` is true, then print the output in desired format, and finally set `pr` as 0 (false)

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt                                                                                                                   
#[Tue Oct 25 00:00:02 2016] --- START OUTPUT
#CMD: XXX
END-->0<--
#[Tue Oct 25 00:00:57 2016] --- END
#RETURN: 1
#ELAPSED TIME (in seconds): 55

#[Tue Oct 25 00:05:01 2016] --- START OUTPUT
#CMD: XXX
END-->0<--
#[Tue Oct 25 00:05:33 2016] --- END
#RETURN: 0
#ELAPSED TIME (in seconds): 32

% awk '/END$/ {prev=$0; next}; /^#RETURN/ && $2>0 {cur=$0; pr=1; next}; pr {printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n", prev, cur, $0; pr=0}' file.txt
#[Tue Oct 25 00:00:57 2016] --- END
#RETURN: 1
#ELAPSED TIME (in seconds): 55
```

Comment: It's a nice algorithm and I love `awk` but isn't it a job more suited for `grep` since the lines are contiguous ?

Comment: @ValentinB. If the file contents are literal, then yes. Although your approach can be made more compact: 1) `egrep` is not needed as there is no ERE token in your pattern 2) Use `-C1` instead of mentioning both `-A` and `-B` as the lien counts are the same. Just do: `grep -C1 'RETURN: [1-9][0-9]*' file.txt`

Comment: Well thank you for the input, I will edit my post accordingly! Had not thought that this was not an *extended* regex, and had forgotten about the context option of `grep`. Yours is indeed more robust but I will leave mine as a "simple" alternative.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this;

```
awk -F: '/#RETURN:/ && $2 > 0 { getline; print $0}' test
```

Eg;

```
user@host:/tmp$ awk -F: '/#RETURN:/ && $2 > 0 { getline; print $0}' test
#ELAPSED TIME (in seconds): 55
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use regular expressions in your `grep`:

```
 grep -C1 'RETURN: [1-9][0-9]*' input.txt
```

That regexp should catch any (positive) number that is not a single 0 (or does not start with a 0).